# 2nd Guard Authenticator overwriting Authentication in place

Tags: symfony

For my app I have 2 different Guard Authenticators in place.

- 1st for traditional website login. (For employees)
- 2nd login via URL-getParameter (for clients -> for previewing things in the system)

Both of them are working fine individually.

But when I'm logged in as employee and then open a page with the get-Param iin place, I get logged in as client (understandable so far)

Can I prevent reauthentication in case I was already loggin in by another method? Before moving to guard this was working.

security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                    - AppBundle\Security\PreviewAuthenticator
                entry_point: AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

Thanks for your advice in advance!

Comment: to my understanding the later simply overwrites the first(s) in yml

Comment: Haven't had much experience with Guard, but you may want to inject security context in each of these and check for existing authenticated user?